# MPI on multiple machines, connection refused

Tags: ubuntu, mpi, mpich, mpiexec

I have two virtual machines running UBuntu 15.04 . I am trying to run a mpicode on these two machines but when I run 
  `mpiexec -verbose -f hostfile python multipoint.py` it gives following error
``

> HYDU_sock_connect (./utils/sock/sock.c:203): unable to connect from "arul-VirtualBox" to "arul-VirtualBox" (Connection refused)
>   [proxy:0:1@arul-VirtualBox] main (./pm/pmiserv/pmip.c:209): unable to connect to server arul-VirtualBox at port 34035 (check for firewalls!)

I can ssh from both machines to each other wihtout specifying username(both machines have same username and file structure). The hostfile contains IP of both the machines running in bridged mode ofthe virtual Box. Also I have disabled the firewall on both of them. Can someone help me.

Comment: Take a look at [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20052397/5148276).

Comment: This answer just tells you to setup everything again, which I did but no success

Comment: I am guessing there's an issue with the port range, look into your `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file. Make sure your arul-VirtualBox uses port 34035 to ssh.